# Does daily updates, update container runtime

Tags: azure, kubernetes, runtime, azure-aks

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/aks/node-updates-kured), I could find that the linux nodes are automatically updated daily. Does the container runtime also getting updated to the latest one? Or do I need to manually updates the container runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AKS, [Moby](https://mobyproject.org/) is used as the container runtime.

**Release 2019-02-12 - Hotfix Release**

**CVE-2019-5736** notes and mitigation Microsoft has built a new version of the Moby container runtime that includes the OCI update to address this vulnerability. In order to consume the updated container runtime release, you will need to upgrade your Kubernetes cluster.

More information you can find here: [aks-update](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/blob/60fd39a428d691ef0cb3152911d772c54a89a8df/CHANGELOG.md#release-2019-02-12---hotfix-release-update)

Overall information about aks you can find here: [aks-core-concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-clusters-workloads).

Comment: thanks for a very insightful answer. But can you please tell me if moby gets updated daily - with AKS daily update?